# Simple FTP sample - connection closing causes files to get trunctated

Tags: cocoa, file-upload, ftp, corruption

I have taken apple's simple FTP Sample and edited it to my needs. (did not change the uploading part)

It reports that the upload went fine, and the file is indeed on the FTP  but if i download the file and open it (jpg images mainly) i get the error message that the file is corrupted.

the only thing i have changed is that when the transfer is finished the connection is forced to close, instad of remaining alive waiting for other uploads.

i think that the program is assigining the last chunk of data to the upload stream and once that is done it assumes that it has finished, without wating for the stream to upload that last chunk.. is that possible? is there a way to see if the networkstream (outputstream) has data in its buffer? i seem to be able to do that only for the inputstream but not for the outpustream.

UPDATE: after comparing the uploaded file with the original file with a hex editor i found out that the files are identical, except that the uploaded one has the final part chopped off. the chopped off part is not allways the same size. it varies between 0 and 256 kb...

UPDATE2:
          `NSLog(@"ntstrm: %zu", self.networkStream.streamStatus);`
is allways returning 2 even while it is uploading. while uploading it should return 4! then after closing it returns 0. but never 4...

UPDATE3:
the only solution i found so far is to put a timer in and wait 15 seconds before i close the connection. but this is not something i want to do because the program i used to upload MANY files and if for each file i ahve to stop 15 seconds its a huge pain.
 any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy to propose a solution given the lack of any fragment of code.

According to your problem description, this can be related to a buffer not flushing properly.

I would suggest you trying to force immediate flush on the output stream. Someone who also wanted to [avoid socket delays](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/290086-flushing-nsoutputstream-gotten-from-nsnetservice.html) did that using TCP_NODELAY just setting some options at socket level:

```
int yes = 1;
setsockopt(CFSocketGetNative(aSocket), IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (void *)&yes, sizeof(yes));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: given that it is the only answer and i cant test it until tonight i give you the 50 reward since it is ending in 3 hours. in the hope that it is what i need. will report back tonight.. thanks!

Comment: This seems to be the correct path! do you know how to apply this to a STREAM? ive been searching without luck.. any help appreciated! thanks..

Comment: Unfortunately my experience in this development environment is very limited, so I can not provide any additional information.